# R aggregate() with dates

Tags: r, dataset, beginner

I am working on a data set that has multiple traffic speed measurements per day. My data is from the city of chicago, and it is taken every minute for about six months. I wanted to consolidate this data into days only, so this is what I did:

```
traffic <- read.csv("path.csv",header=TRUE)
traffic2 <- aggregate(SPEED~DATE, data=traffic, FUN=MEAN)
```

this was perfect because it took all of my data and averaged it by date. For example, my original data looked something like this:

```
DATE        SPEED  
12/31/2012   22
12/31/2012   25
12/31/2012   23
...
```

and the final looked like this:

```
DATE        SPEED 
10/1/2012    22
10/2/2012    23
10/3/2012    22
...
```

The only problem, is my data is supposed to start at 9/1/2012. I plotted this data, and it turns out the data goes from 10/1/2012-12/31/2012 and then 9/1/2012-9/30/2012.

What in the world is going on here?

Comment: What class is the Date column? It looks like it might be sorting by character (1 comes before 9) rather than date value.

Comment: Base R read.csv() converts strings to factor. I agree with @user1683454; you will find that your dates are in alphabetical order.

Comment: You should probably ask this on stackoverflow, its a basic R programming question, not really data science.

Comment: @Spacedman good point. I will put it there next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to agree with @user1683454's comment. After importing, your DATE column is of either `character`, or `factor` class (depending on your settings for `stringsAsFactors`). Therefore, I think that you can solve this issue in at least several ways, as follows:

1) **Convert data** to correct type **during import**. To do this, just use the following options of `read.csv()`: `stringsAsFactors` (or `as.is`) and `colClasses`. By default, you can specify conversion to `Date` or `POSIXct` classes. If you need a non-standard format, you have two options. First, if you have a single Date column, you can use `as.Date.character()` to pass the desired format to `colClasses`. Second, if you have multiple Date columns, you can write a function for that and pass it to `colClasses` via `setAs()`. Both options are discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022299/specify-date-format-for-colclasses-argument-in-read-table-read-csv.

2) **Convert data** to correct format **after import**. Thus, after calling `read.csv()`, you would have to execute the following code: `dateColumn <- as.Date(dateColumn, "%m/%d/%Y")` or `dateColumn <- strptime(dateColumn, "%m/%d/%Y")` (adjust the format to whatever Date format you need).

Comment: As an addendum, I'd recommend taking a look at the `lubridate` package, which can make certain date manipulation tasks simpler.

Comment: @ssdecontrol: Agree, thanks for the comment. Upvoted.